# Displaying xib from collectionView embedded in tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I am trying to display a xib of a collectionViewCell from the tableViewCell (so I can do both horizontal and vertical scrolling while having categories per row). It seems that the register of the xib is where the issue is coming into play as it will not register it properly from the proper place? tableView cannot be registering it since it fails when I tried to do so, I have registered it in the collectionView but where it wont crash but nothing displays. Maybe this isn't the best way to do it - but what would be a good alternative to implement a spaced out horizontal scrolling and vertical scrolling? Here is my source code so far

```
import UIKit

class DiscoverViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var discoverTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}

extension DiscoverViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "DiscoverCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "DiscoverCollectionViewCell")

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "DiscoverCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DiscoverCollectionViewCell

        cell.authorLabel.text = "this"
        cell.coverImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "discover")
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        5
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = discoverTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CategoryTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CategoryTableViewCell

        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out, the delegate and datasource had to be set to the TableView cell file as well as registering the xib on the TV with an instance of the CV on there. thanks to @Daniel for a point in the right direction.